# Float value is too long when rendered in Jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have some float values that represent percentages, but they have too many decimal places. How can I display a shorter value in my Jinja template?

```
{% for item in items %}
{{ item.name }}
{{ item.score }}%
{% endfor %}
```

```
person
10.2419833200485471%
```

I'd like to display "10.24%" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use the round filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#round). The documentation shows some ways you can control the rounding.

```
{{ item.score|round(2) }}
```